# How to add ipython syntax highlighting to pygmentize?

Tags: python, colors, syntax-highlighting, ipython, pygments

I need syntax highlighting in a latex project, using the minted package I can use the pygments lexers, there is a lexer for ipython [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/nbconvert/utils/lexers.py).

How can I add this to pygments ?? (windows or OSX)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this github project:

https://github.com/sanguineturtle/pygments-ipython-console

This package provides a Pygments_ lexer for IPython Console Files. The lexer is published as an entry point and, once installed, Pygments will pick it up automatically.